# Stange behaviour with getElementsByTagName in Tampermonkey script

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

My Goal:
I have a quite complex web page from which I ike to extract some information.
The information is contained in a div. But the div has no name and the page has about a zillion divs on it.

I found out, the page has only seven  and the second section contains the div that I am searching for. Okay, a tampermonkey script like this should work:

```
allSection = document.getElementsByTagName('section');
console.log ("First Section", allSection );
console.log ("Length All Section", allSection.length);
```

When I print the result of the getElementByTagname, it has seven sections (as expected).
Chrome console shows the HTMLCollection in a very nice prittyprint. I can find my information there.

But already the next line says, the HTMLCollection is only 1 element long

Even stranger:
I can access the first section with allSection[0], but not the second one with allSection[1].
This is consistent with the printed length (1), but not with the printed HTMLCollection.

Any idea?

Comment: Please provide code sufficient to replicate the problem.

Comment: if you need a stable list, use `document.querySelectorAll('section')`. The `getElementsByTagName` function returns a _live_ HTMLCollection (i.e. it will change as necessary to _always_ reflect the DOM) whereas `querySelectorAll` returns a fixed list, which will only ever reflect what the DOM was like when you queried it.

Comment: Add `allSection = [...allSection]`, and see if you still have the problem.

Comment: @addis: thanks for remindnig me to reduce the problem to the bar minimum. Will do. The page I am examining is from a big Internet Service provider.
@ mike: I used the querySelectorAll as well, Somehow similar effect, the list is only one element long. It is not  HTMLCollection anymore, but a NodeList.
@ trincot2: need to make myself familar with your comment, not fully understanding what you suggest. But appreciate the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, the answer is very easy.

The elements I was looking for were not yet loaded.
They resulted from AJAX calls. So basically, when the script
was running, the elements did not exist.
When I looked at the chrome console, the elements exist and the console
was able to show them.

Solution:
I have a crude solution, waiting a few milliscond
until the elements are loaded:

setTimeout(function() {}, 2000);

Comment: If you need a more sophisticated solution, look up dom observer for observing changes to HTML and reacting upon them.